# How to give this an id Javascript using innerHTML changing image size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find a easy way of making a pop-up box that uses the image al-ready in a link using function (this);.
however I would like to change the size of the image in the pop up box however I am having problems targeting it.
I tried to give it an id but that does not work.

```
   function fullScreenpopup(x){
    var b = x.innerHTML;
    var divpopup = document.createElement("div");
    divpopup.innerHTML = b + '<a href = "javascript:void(0)" 
    onclick ="fullScreengetrid()">Close</a>';
    b.id = "imagepopup"; // this line does not work
    divpopup.setAttribute('class', 'white_content_philips');
    divpopup.setAttribute('id', 'popupbox');
    document.body.appendChild(divpopup);
    var popupdiv = document.createElement("div");
    popupdiv.setAttribute('class', 'black_overlay_philips');
    popupdiv.setAttribute('id', 'fadepopup');
    document.body.appendChild(popupdiv);
   }
```

any ideas please?

This is what the code relates to

```
<div style="float:left;">
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick ="fullScreenpopup(this)"><img 
src="acb.jpg" 
alt="abc" width="300" height="225" 
class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-1807" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `x`, What HTML does this JavaScript relate to?

Comment: Sorry I have added the code

Comment: There's a line-break in your code at `divpopup.inner ...`. Make it a single line.

Comment: sorry I put the line breaks in to make it easier to read so people did not have to scroll

Comment: `b` is a string, so `b.id = ...` won't do anything. You might mean `divpopup.id = ...`

Comment: well I want to target b that will hold the image and I want to adjust the size. so I was trying to give it a id so I can alter the size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `id` is getting assigned correctly in the DOM and you can verify this through the debugger. I think your biggest issue is assigning `width` and `height` to the image in HTML. This will override any changes you make in CSS. Try.

```
<img src="acb.jpg"
     alt="abc"
     class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-1807" />
```